# Ленивая загрузка объектов (Lazy loading) Java + Spring + JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lazyloading

Нужно сделать ленивую загрузку для объектов, не вызывая `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.`

конфигурация JPA :

```
    @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("education.web.platform");

    entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateJpaProperties());
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {

    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}

private Map<String, ?> hibernateJpaProperties() {
    HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));


    return properties;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Пример возникновения проблемы:

Загружаемый класс:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "theory_tasks")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "task_id")
public class TheoryTask extends Task {
...
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ProbablyAnswer.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "task")
private List<ProbablyAnswer> probablyAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

Класс объектов для ленивой загрузки:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "probably_answers")
public class ProbablyAnswer implements Serializable{
...
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
private Task task;
...
```

Если метод получающий список объектов в `DAO` помечен `@Transactional` то при обращении к списку `ProbablyAnswers` в `TheoryTask` они не подгружаются и при передаче его на страницу выбрасывается `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException.`

Если пометить `@Transactional` метод в сервисе или контроллере то ленивая загрузка игнорируется и рекурсивно загружается весь граф объектов.

Метод которым я получаю сущность:

```
 public List<T> getAll(){
    String genericClassName = persistentClass.toGenericString();
    genericClassName = genericClassName.substring(genericClassName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    String hql = "FROM "+genericClassName;
    return  entityManager.createQuery(hql,persistentClass).getResultList();
}
```

В дальнейшем сущности выводятся на html страницу.

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос, какими методами получаете из БД и как в дальнейшем используются сущности в сервисе, чтоб можно было воспроизвести.

Comment: @MrFylypenko дополнил

Answer (score 1):

Перед тем как использовать полученный список, проинициализируйте его утилитой `Hibernate.initialize(yourList)`

```
public List<T> getAll(){
    String genericClassName = persistentClass.toGenericString();
    genericClassName = genericClassName.substring(genericClassName.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
    String hql = "FROM "+genericClassName;
    List<T> list = entityManager.createQuery(hql,persistentClass).getResultList();
    Hibernate.initialize(list);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: вы можете обосновать свой ответ? потому как везде пишут что использование Hibernate.initialize(), без использования кеша второго уровня будет вызывать проблему N+1

Answer (score 0):

Все сущности с дочерними можно получить одним запросом к БД, для этого переопределите в имплементации Ваш метод и укажите какие дочерние объекты нужно прогрузить, например так:

```
 public List<TheoryTask> getAll(){   
    String hql = "FROM TheoryTask t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.probablyAnswers";
    return  entityManager.createQuery(hql,TheoryTask.class).getResultList();
}
```

В БД будет идти один запрос и будет применятся только для этого метода.